# Reducing textheight and increasing footskip does not work on first page after front page

Tags: margins

I want to add a graphic to the bottom of all my pages apart from the front page. I am reducing textheight and increasing footskip using \addtolength{} but it does not have any affect on the first page (after front page). Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\title{Lorem ipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\clearpage

\makeatletter
\addtolength{\textheight}{-68mm}
\addtolength{\footskip}{68mm}

\AddToShipoutPicture{
            \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth}
            \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.21\paperheight}
            \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt}
            \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){
       \makebox(0,0) {
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{2mm}
            \fbox{
               \includegraphics{Some-logo.jpg}
            }
       }
   }
}

\begin{center}
{\huge\sc chaptertitle}
\vspace{8mm}
\end{center} 

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

My LaTeX knowledge is still minimal. Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: Do not change `\textheight` or `\textwidth` after `\begin{document}` LaTeX simply does not support that. You can use `\enlargethispage{1cm}` to change the effective size of one page.

Comment: You are missing `%` from almost all the lines of your code, as written they will introduce a lot of spurious space in the output.

Comment: As David wrote, it is seldom necessary to change `\textheight` after `\begin{document}`. But if you must do it: As you can see in your example such changes affect the next page, so move the changes to the previous page (before the `\clearpage`).

Comment: @Ulrike, your comment regarding moving the `\clearpage` command helped me find the problem in my code. Thanks.

Comment: @David, I had wondered what `%` was meant to do at the end of a line. Now I know! Thanks.